# gulp-uglify cannot change the name

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm using gulp-uglify to minify my code, and there's a thing I would like to change .

I have the next `gulpfile.js` . When I do `gulp calendar-uglify` I got the compile inside /compile/ directory and with the name `calendar.min.js`. If I change the name inside `uglify` and I run again the command, gulp generates the name before again.

I mean, it seems that uglify cannot compile the file with the name I wrote. Gulp-uglify allways takes the filename of the concat file.

What can I do to change that?

TY,

Jaster

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Dependencies
var   gulp      = require('gulp'),
      concat    = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify    = require('gulp-uglify');

// Private callbacks

/**
 * Calendar js concat
 * @private
 **/
var _calendarConcat = function(){
  return gulp.src(['./src/olympics/Calendar.js', './src/entry/calendar.js'])
    .pipe(concat('calendar.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
};

/**
 * Calendar js uglify
 * @private
 **/
var _calendarUglify = function(){
  return gulp.src('./dist/calendar.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify('calendar.min.js', {
      mangle: true,
      output: {
        beautify: true
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./compile/'));
};

// Task def

gulp.task('calendar-concat', _calendarConcat);
gulp.task('calendar-uglify', _calendarUglify);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`gulp-uglify` documentation](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) doesn't explicitly state the method signature for `uglify()` anywhere, but you can look at [the source code](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/minifier.js#L46) to figure it out. It's essentially this:

```
uglify([opts, [uglify]])
```

Where

- `opts` is an optional map of [options](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify#options).
- `uglify` is an optional [instance of uglifyJs](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify#using-a-different-uglifyjs)

So there's no way specify a different file name using `uglify()`.

There's no need for that anyway. Gulp plugins are supposed to do one thing and one thing well. That way you can combine them into more complex pipelines.

In your case you're looking for the [`gulp-rename` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) which let's you rename a file:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var _calendarUglify = function(){
  return gulp.src('./dist/calendar.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify({
      mangle: true,
      output: {
        beautify: true
      }
    }))
    // renames the file to calendar2.min.js
    .pipe(rename({basename:'calendar2.min'})) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./compile/'));
};
```