# How can I gzip a uglify js with Gulp without generating two file in dist folder

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

I'm new using Gulp.

I'm wondering how can I concat, uglify and gzip all the js files from a static website using Gulp.

I have a task like this that works but I would like to only include in the dist folder the .gz file and not the combined.js

```
gulp.task("concat-js", function () {
return gulp.src("./src/js/*.js")
    .pipe(concat("combined.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/js"));
});
```

**UPDATE**

I encourage you to read the comments. In my case, the problem has been caused by a bad use of gulp-useref, because was generating the file at the end of the build process.  Probably noob problem, but hopefully can help anyone.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why gzip them when you can have your server do it?

Comment: I'm going to use S3 + Cloud front to serve my website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  Just store the .min file in a temp folder.  You can delete that later if you want.

```
gulp.task("concat-js", function () {
  return gulp.src("./src/js/*.js")
   .pipe(concat("combined.min.js"))

   .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp'))

   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gzip())
   .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/js"));
});
```

The final file would be "combined.min.js.gz" the only one in build/js.  If you don't like that name you could rename it with [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I still see the two file generated in the build folder

Comment: Hmmm, I ran this a few times to verify.  Did you delete your build folder first to start with a clean slate?

Comment: Look like the uglify() is creating the additional file in the build/js folder. Because I see in the temp folder the combined.js (no uglify file) and in build/js combined.min.js (uglify file)

Comment: I get one file (combined.min.css) in the temp folder and one file (combined.min.css.gz) in the build/js folder.  You did delete both of those folders first before running this?  So those aren't old files there from before?  I just say that because it works flawlessly for me.

Comment: I always delete the folder before running the build.   I just find out that it works for css files but not for js files.

I think works for you because you are using css files, can you try with js files?

Comment: I tried with both.  I just forgot to change the concat(....css) to .js.   But it works fine with both kinds of files.  I made a test situation of your folder structure with a couple of js files in it.  You have something else unrelated going on.  Gulp-uglify doesn't change any filenames https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244655/gulp-uglify-cannot-change-the-name

Comment: Mark, what is the version of gulp-uglify, gulp-rename, gulp-concat that you are using?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: uglify : 3.0.0    ;   rename : 1.2.2   :   concat  :  2.6.1

Comment: Mark, looks like gulp-userref is creating and overriding the file :( when I try to substitute the multiple javascripts in the html.  I'm going to change some things but I think you're right and seems a problem from my site of the bad usage of gulp-userref

Comment: I hope you figure it out.  In the meantime, if you can verify that my answer is correct it would help others to know that by your accepting it as so.  You could ask another question showing how you are incorporating useref and the resultant filenames.